# Can an inherited class override another inherited class' virtual function?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Is the following legal?

```
class Base {
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class Fooable {
    void foo(){}
};

class Child : public Base, public Fooable {

};
```

What happens if a class inherits from two classes which both have `foo()`? What if `Base::foo()` werent abstract?

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since foo is virtual in Base, if you don't implement foo() in Child then compilation fails if you try to instantiate Child, since Child is still abstract.

If Base::foo() were not abstract, you'd need to specify which foo you were calling as follows:
`Child *child = new Child;` `child->Base::foo()`; `child->Fooable::foo()`

Answer (score 0):

Since `Base` and `Fooable` don't have a comment virtual base, when you inherit from both of them, you get two independent `foo` functions that don't interact despite having the same name.

You can do what you want by using common virtual base classes:

```
class Base {
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class Fooable : public virtual Base {
    void foo(){}
};

class Child : public virtual Base, public virtual Fooable {

};
```

Though if you want to be able to call `foo`, you'll need to make it public rather than private.